# How to change TTL of a DNS record on IIS

Tags: iis, dns, ttl

How do I change the Time To Live (TTL) of a DNS record in IIS 7?  The Properties for the record do not have this field.

This is important because the SORBS DUHL blacklist requires that an MX record have a TTL of 12 hours.

Comment: IIS is a web server, it has nothing to do with DNS.  You need to change it on whatever platform you have your DNS server running on.

Comment: I am referring to the DNS server that is included with IIS.  Although it is true that they are separate Roles installed in Server Manager, it's pretty obvious what I am talking about.

Comment: What windows version are you using?

Comment: Using Windows 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you referring to the DNS Manager roll on a Windows machine with IIS installed.

To modify the individual records do the following;

In DNS manager click; `view -> advanced`. Then open the DNS record. There will be some additional fields including the TTL.

Works on server 2003 - 2012 R2

Some document links [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197418(WS.10).aspx) which explain how to set via the registry, and a youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p580ttd1fDg) showing the GUI (which should apply to Server 2012).